# pandas.DataFrame.loc won't work for indexing dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to look for a piece of data by date and value, however, I keep getting an error. Here is the code:

```
eth.loc['2020-08-13', 'Value']
```

Here is the error:

```
        352                 except ValueError as err:
        353                     raise KeyError(key) from err
    --> 354             raise KeyError(key)
        355         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
        356 
    
    KeyError: '2020-08-13'
```

Thanks!

Comment: please try `eth.loc[eth.columnname=='2020-08-13', 'Value']`. where columnname is maybe date. Alternatively post the eth sample dataframe

Comment: According to the docs, `df.loc` will raise a `Key Error` if any items are not found. It seems you don't have `'2020-08-13'`, if you share a snippet of the data we could help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Assumming you've a dataset defined by:

```
eth = pd.DataFrame([['2020-08-13', 2], ['2020-08-14', 5], ['2020-08-15', 8]], 
                    index=['book1','book2','book3'], 
                    columns=['Date','Value'])
```

You can get items with value say 2:

```
eth.loc[eth['Value'] == 2]
```

You can get items with date say 2020-08-13:

```
eth.loc[eth['Date'] == '2020-08-13']
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer turned out to be `eth.loc[eth.columnname=='2020-08-13', 'Value']`, thanks to @wwnde for the help!